# How SQL Server orders the result set of SELECT statement on Clustered Indexed Table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `table1` (`id, col1, col2, col3, text`), `id` is the primary key and has a clustered index on it.

When I run query

```
Select * from table1
```

I got result as following, which is as expected

```
id  col1    col2    col3    text
---------------------------------
779 027 15  001 test1
780 027 15  600 test1
781 027 15  001 test2
782 027 15  600 test2
783 027 15  001 test3
784 027 15  600 test3
```

but if I run following query

```
select * from table1
order by col1, col2, col3
```

I got this

```
id  col1    col2    col3    text
---------------------------------
779 027 15  001 test1
781 027 15  001 test2
783 027 15  001 test3
784 027 15  600 test3
782 027 15  600 test2
780 027 15  600 test1
```

My question is why the last three records is in the opposite order as the first three record?

Comment: You want the rows ordered by `col1, col2, col3` - and you're getting that - right? There's nothing wrong with this - you get what you ask for. Anything else (any further "ordering" without an explicit `ORDER BY`) is not guaranteed - SQL Server can return the data in whatever order it likes (and whatever order is fastest)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the order.

The first query isn't ordered at all, but the second query is (according to col1, col2 and col3), hence the different results...

Comment: In the first query, the results **are not ordered at all** - without an **explicit `ORDER BY`**, there is **no guaranteed order** at all!